# How to fix background image Responsive with ng-style in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, background

I have attached jpg background image responsive view gap space how to fix it any one help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuJjN.jpg)

Comment: please paste a snippet too @jagarapu

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your background image class:

`{background-size:cover;}`

or

`{background-size:auto 100%;}`